# Simple proof by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I feel like I'm almost there, but I don't know what to right after this:

for all real number $x$, if $x^2-2x\neq-1$, then $x\neq-1$.

Let $p(x)$ be $x^2-2x\neq-1$

Let $q(x)$ be $x\neq-1$,

My textbook says suppose that we can find a contradiction q such that
'not p $\rightarrow q$' because $q$ is false, but 'not $p \rightarrow q$' is true.

I understand the value of $x$ from 'not $p(x)$'is 1, but I'm not sure I should write all that words every time I solve the proof questions.

And I think I'm not understanding it very well. Without the words, I can solve simple proof by contradiction problems though. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $q(x): x \neq 1$ holds. Then, we want:
$$\neg P(x) \Rightarrow Q,$$
but, $\neg P(x) \Rightarrow x^2 -2x+1 = 0 \Rightarrow x = 1$. A contradiction, since we are assuming that $x \neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The proposition you want to prove is $r$, that is

$$r = \forall x ~:~ p(x) \rightarrow q(x)$$

To establish a proof by contradiction, you assume $\lnot r$, and follow the implications (the following statements are all logically equivalent):

$$\lnot r$$
$$\lnot \bigg(\forall x ~:~ p(x) \rightarrow q(x)\bigg)$$
$$\exists x ~:~ \lnot \bigg(p(x) \rightarrow q(x)\bigg)$$
$$\exists x ~:~ \lnot \bigg(\lnot p(x) \text{ or } q(x)\bigg)$$
$$\exists x ~:~ p(x) \text{ and } \lnot q(x)$$
$$\exists x ~:~ x^2 - 2x \ne -1 \text{ and } x=1$$

The only possible value of $x$ that can witness $x=1$ is (try to guess...) $x=1$.  But if $x = 1$, then $x^2 - 2x \ne -1$ fails to be true, so the final statement is false, which is a goal of a proof by contradiction.